# Jenkins - Running only single job in slave other - in master

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins server with 50+ jobs.
I added a new one that requires execution with specific user.
So I created the slave node (same host with specific configurations) and restricted it to slave.
But all my old jobs started to use master + slave. So they started to failed (because I used another user).

How I can add new slave node and restrict all jobs by default use the master except several jobs?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your new slave, did you try to configure the usage like below?

[image]

With this setting, all the existing jobs should not use the new node.